# How can an Android App read a Wordpress Site's RSS Feed that requires log-in?

Tags: android, wordpress, rss

Assuming that we have a wordpress site that requires its visitors to log-in to access/view its contents, is there a way for every installation of an android application to read this site's RSS Feed? The site's contents, besides the RSS Feed, shouldn't be visible to the public.

Because so far, my findings tell me that this isn't possible: https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/public-rss-feed-for-a-private-blog

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You log in.  Make the same HTTP request that the login form does.  Get the result.  Use the authentication info and pass it up the same way the website does.  Pretty much like you do to access any private web api.

Comment: i thought so... so there isn't a way for the android app to access the rss feed without logging-in? thanks

Comment: If you said it requires you to be logged in, no. Now if it's a public feed, then you can just download it.

Comment: but is there a way for the wordpress site to be private, but its rss feed isn't? thanks again.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? If the rss feed is public, then all the information is there anyway. What's the value in not letting them see it on the website when they can download it all?